# Pandas Lambda OR / AND Statements Across Columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a new column [Check] that looks at my [Color] column and my [Size] column to say if the color is blue and size is greater than 50, then the column should be the Owner, else leave it blank.

IF Color = Blue & Size > 50, THEN [Owner] ELSE null

I have the following:

```
df['Check'] = df['Color'].apply(lambda x,y: df['Owner'] if (x == 'Blue') & (y > 50) else null)
```

What I'm not sure how to do is tell the apply function to include Color as x and Size as y. And then for OR/AND statements in a lambda formula, is it the same as if you were filtering a dataeframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work (without `lambda`-function):

```
df['Check'] = df['Owner'][(df['Color'] == 'Blue') & (df['Size'] > 50)]
```

I've tried it with

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Blue', 25, 'Owner1'],
                   ['Blue', 55, 'Owner2'],
                   ['Green', 100, 'Owner3']],
                  columns=['Color', 'Size', 'Owner'])
```

and got the following result

```
   Color  Size   Owner   Check
0   Blue    25  Owner1     NaN
1   Blue    55  Owner2  Owner2
2  Green   100  Owner3     NaN
```

(With `apply` the `lambda`-function can only take one argument.)

**Explanation**: `(df['Color'] == 'Blue')` and `(df['Size'] > 50)` create series with `True`/`False` values according the the conditions (you can print them). Both series are combined by the logical `AND` (using `&`) into a new series, also containing `True`/`False` values (now according the `AND`-combined conditions). Finally the column `df['Owner']` takes the series and keeps all rows in which the series has `True` als value and fills the rest with `NaN`.

Comment: I haven't seen that format before... Could you explain what that's doing?

Comment: @RCarmody I tried (see edit). I've always assumed this is the standard way to do such stuff ...

Comment: Thank you! That makes more sense with the explanation... Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` on a column, but you can also use it on a dataframe itself. You'll need to provide an axis (row or columns) if you are using the dataframe.

`f = lambda row: row['Owner'] if (row['Color'] == 'Blue') & (row['Size'] > 50) else null`

`df['Check'] = df.apply(f,axis=1)`

Comment: Now I have learned something new! I try to minimise the use of lambdas, though.

Comment: But you probably don't want to use `null` but rather something like `np.NaN` or `None`?